# how to use set/p for find command so if I enter a word it can see if it is in the list

Tags: batch-file

so lets say I have a list of words and I want the user to type in a prompt
`set/p "prompt=>"`
`find "%prompt%" example.txt`

ive tried this but it will just print
`---------- EXAMPLE.TXT`

I have no clue what im doing somewhat because this is my first time really trying to do batch coding

Comment: I suppose your command should have looked more like, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%prompt%" 0<"P:\athTo\example.txt" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Echo found.) || Echo Not found.```. As a side note, I would certainly opt for `findstr.exe` over `find.exe`

Comment: If Im reading this right you want to prompt for text and find it in a file?

Comment: `prompt` is a reserved variable-name. It controls how the system prompt appear in the `cmd` window. Choose another name. The response is correct if `example.txt` does not contain the string you entered. Try `find /i` in place of `find` to make the comparison case-insensitive. The system will set the reserved variable `errorlevel` to `0` if the `find` was successful, `1` otherwise. To suppress the `--- filename`, redirect the input to `find` like `find "%findme%"<example.txt`. HTH - you haven't said what you want to do when the user enters a string that is(n't) in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set "ListPath=C:\temp"
set "ListFile=List.txt"

:loop
set /p "FindWord=Enter a new word for the list: "

findstr /i /n "%FindWord%" "%ListPath%\%ListFile%"

if %errorlevel% == 0 echo %FindWord% is in the list
if not %errorlevel% == 0 echo %FindWord% is not in the list

Choice /m "Search for another word?"

if %errorlevel% == 1 goto loop
```

Try this. This script uses the `findstr` command to look for the entered word in the specified file.